# Keeping associative bracketing in place

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The following Mathematica code displays the vertices of a given graph after converting an expression into a suitable format (using heads that are tensor and parallel notation. The labels are displayed at the vertices, but associativity rules are used. How can I prevent this from happening (i.e. how can I keep the brackets when vertices are displayed?

```
DiplayGraph[g_] := 
  With[{vlist = VertexList[g]}, 
    Graph[g, VertexLabels -> 

    Thread[
     vlist -> Map[# /. {ExpProduct -> (ToString[
              HoldForm[CircleTimes[##]]] &), 
          Parallel -> (ToString[
              HoldForm[DoubleVerticalBar[##]]] &)} &, vlist]], 
   EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[10, Background -> White], 
   VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[10, Background -> White]]]
```

When executing this code on a graph:

```
DisplayGraph[Graph[{A[1, 2] -> B[2, B[3, 4]]}]]
```

the following output is generated:

[image: displaygraph]

I would like 2 || 3 || 4 to appear as 2 || (3 || 4) consistent with the parentheses in B[2, B[3, 4]] (i.e. I don't want the associative removal of the parentheses). Which command can be inserted to ensure this?

Comment: Presumably you meant to use `Parallel[2, Parallel[3, 4]]`? In any case, why are you converting things to strings? Don't do that. Instead, just use `Parallel -> DoubleVerticalBar`.

Comment: Thanks Carl, that resolved it indeed.